# How to return a string containing information about how many values exist for each key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I currently have the following:

```
 mydict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

I want to return a string containing quantities of items available in the dictionary. For example

```
a: 3
b: 2
```

However, I want my output to update if I add another key value pair to the dictionary. For example mydict['c'] = [1, 2, 3]

I have thought about how to do this and this is all that comes to mind:

```
def quantities() -> str:

     mydict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2]}

     for k, v in mydict:
        print(f'{k}: {len(v)})
```

But I am not sure if this is correct. Are there any other ways to do this.

Comment: I think you'll need [`mydict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
for <variable> in mydict:
```

Iterates through only the keys of the dictionary. So, you can either use the key to get the item like:

```
mydict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2]}
for k in mydict:
    print(f'{k}: {len(mydict[k])}')
```

Or use `mydict.items()` This makes it iterate through every `(key, value)`. USe it as:

```
mydict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2]}
for k, v in mydict.items():
    print(f'{k}: {len(v)}')
```

Comment: If I were to, having this function return a string. For example def quantities() -> str: I am not sure if this code would still work. or it would have to be modified ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your sample code will work. I used [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) and use `sorted()`  I think what you want is something like this.

```
mydict = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [1, 2]}

def quantities():
    for k, v in sorted(mydict.items()):
        print(k, len(v))
        
quantities()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `str.join` and a generator expression:

```
def quantities(mydict):
    return '\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, len(v)) for k, v in mydict.items())
```